# How to calculate the accuracy for multilabel classification with tf.metrics?

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, tensorflow-estimator

I want to train multilabel classification model with tensorflow (tf.estimator.Estimator). I need to output the accuracy when do evaluating. But it seem not work with the following code:

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=preds)
metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
```

the `tf.metrics.accuracy` is not for multihot result. So what is the multilabel metrics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [`tf.metrics.accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) calculates the accuracy for multilabel classification as well. See the example below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [1, 1, 0, 0]])

preds = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1, 1],
                     [0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 0, 0]])

acc, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, preds)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([acc, acc_op]))
    print(sess.run([acc]))
```

As you can see we have 20 labels in total that only one entry, in the first row, is mislabeled as a result our accuracy is 0.95%.

Comment: `module 'tensorflow.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'accuracy'`